# jquery dialog zindex setting won't work in second open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
subscribeDialog = $('#metrics-subscribe-popup').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        zIndex: 20,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {

                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


subscribeDialog.dialog('open')
```

When I use subscribeDialog.dialog('open') to open the dialog at second time, the zIndex is not work.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Dialog open and close has nothing to do with the z-index property of dialog.

But you can also set explicitly the z-index on second open like this

```
subscribeDialog.dialog({
     zIndex: 100
});
subscribeDialog.dialog('open');
```